# Maven picking wrong slf4j version

Tags: maven, slf4j

I have a maven project which has the direct dependency as follows:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <optional>false</optional>
</dependency>
```

but in spite of this, the `mvn dependency:tree` shows `slf4j-api` version chosen as `1.6.2`, and as direct dependency to my project!

There are other dependencies in my project which might depend on some other version of `slf4j`. But my understanding is that the version specified nearest to the root of the tree is picked up.

Other dependencies on `slf4j` related stuff are `org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.5:compile`, `org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.5:compile` (direct dependencies) and `org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.3:runtime` (transitive dependency)

I am building a `war` in this maven project, and the jar of `slf4j` included is at `1.6.2` in the archive. I don't know what to do to make sure I get the jar version `1.7.5` and not `1.6.2`.

Update: I am using maven `3.0.4`.

Update 2: As requested, the pom and the debug logs are added. Since the files were huge, I've added it to dropbox Public folder: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/w1rtgvxvnt4jf18/lbiMIgwWD_

Comment: There may be some other dependency _requiring_ version 1.6.2 specifically `<version>[1.6.2]</version>`...  Heres a good write up: http://guntherpopp.blogspot.com/2011/02/understanding-maven-dependency.html

Comment: @Lucas how does someone require 1.6.2 specifically? If someone gave the version as [1.6.2] in square brackets, it would fail to resolve dependencies. But build is successful. Btw, I already read that writeup trying to search for solutions on google :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Maven: remove a single transitive dependency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816858/maven-remove-a-single-transitive-dependency)

Comment: Post the output of `mvn dependency:tree -Ddebug` (as well as your full `pom.xml`).

Comment: Please avoid putting things behind a link. There is lots of room in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, proximity rules apply so that the declaration nearest the current project wins. You might want to remove the `<optional>false</optional>` element and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: doesnt work :-( It was not working before, and I added it to see if it works.