# Maven dependencies. Asking for aws-java-sdk jar 1.6.8 but getting 1.5.0

Tags: maven

I'v declared the dependency for **com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:jar:1.6.8**, but I'm getting jar **1.5.0**.
While running **mvn dependency:tree**, I see the following line:

> com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:jar:1.5.0:compile (version managed from
>   1.6.8)

What does it mean? How do I resolve it and actuaully get 1.6.8?

Comment: use google :) see [maven-remove-a-single-transitive-dependency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816858/maven-remove-a-single-transitive-dependency)

Answer (score 1):

It means that in your `pom.xml` or in the parent of your `pom.xml`, their a `dependencyManagement` section that declares that the version of `com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk` must be the `1.5.0`.

Comment: I thought so too, but still - I don't see it. I'll keep digging deeper in. Thx!

Comment: You can try `mvn help:effective-pom | more` and check if a `dependencyManagement` section appears.