# How to use jarjar from the command-line?

Tags: java, scala, jar, jarjar

I'm having trouble using jarjar from the command-line to combine a simple Scala program with the scala runtime-library.

jarjar correctly detects the dependency:

```
$ java -jar ~/Desktop/saug/jarjar-1.0.jar find jar BCT.jar scala-library.jar
/home/schani/Work/scala/bct/BCT.jar -> /home/schani/Work/scala/bct/scala-library.jar
```

Combining them doesn't work, however:

```
$ CLASSPATH=./scala-library.jar java -jar ~/Desktop/saug/jarjar-1.0.jar process rules.jjl BCT.jar BCTS.jar
```

The jar file that I get still depends on scala-library.jar.  Whether or not I add the CLASSPATH variable makes no difference.  My rules.jjl file looks like this:

```
keep BCT
```

What to do?

Comment: It's just a jedi mind trick.  Hopefully it doesn't bink you up too much.....

Answer (score 1):

Using the java "-jar" option ignores the classpath. Try specifying the main class explicitly with a classpath, and omit "-jar":

```
java -cp ~/Desktop/saug/jarjar-1.0.jar:./scala-library.jar com.tonicsystems.jarjar.Main process rules.jjl BCT.jar BCTS.jar
```

Comment: For me, to be more specific it creates a jar, which just contains BCT.jar. I don't want to rename any package, but collect all dependencies. So in the rules I have one keep rule with the package of the main class in my BCT.jar

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a keep for the scala.runtime.Nothing$ class.  I found this necessary when using a similar product (autojar; http://autojar.sourceforge.net/en_d/index.html) with Scala.

Comment: That doesn't work, either.  jarjar seems to only take classes from the input jar file specified on the command line, but not from any dependent jars, and there doesn't seem to be a way to specify them.

Answer (score 0):

jarjar does not repackage other jars into your jar. It only renames dependencies inside the one jar itself.

Use the method outlined here [Clean way to combine multiple jars? Preferably using Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515428/clean-way-to-combine-multiple-jars-preferably-using-ant) to rejar all the dependent jars into your jar, then run jarjar to prevent future dependency hell.

Comment: actually, just rezipping using the ant task is not the most ideal solution. i used the eclipse fat-jar plugin to do this. basically, make an empty project and put all the jars in the build path of the project then use the fat-jar plugin http://fjep.sourceforge.net/ to export to a fat jar.