# How to Export Several Classes to a JAR in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, class, jar, compilation

So, I'm running Eclipse Java Photon, and I have four classes, all with `JFrame`s. Within the program, I need to run the `JFrame` from another class, like if the user clicks a settings button, it opens a class with the dialogue for that. The program works perfectly, as-is, but when compiled to a JAR file it only opens the first class (the one with which it was built), and none of the others **unless** it is in the same directory as the other classes.

Is it possible for me to combine all of these classes into one JAR file, so I do not need the other classes lying around?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make a single jar file of multiple classes that can be used in other projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151952/how-to-make-a-single-jar-file-of-multiple-classes-that-can-be-used-in-other-proj)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515428/clean-way-to-combine-multiple-jars-preferably-using-ant

Comment: http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISengine/java/doc/5bf81818-3805-44c6-af50-2e223ad27870.htm