# Java : create jar executable with dependant jars embedded

Tags: java, jar, executable

I have created an executable JAR with the manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: MyClass
Class-Path: lib/ext.jar
```

I can successfully run this JAR if I have folder **lib** with dependent **ext.jar** in the folder of .jar created.

I would like to embed **ext.jar** in my executable JAR to launch it anywhere I want, without creating lib folder. This would allow the JAR file to be self-contained, including all of its dependencies.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I would suggest building with Maven. See link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729054/include-dependencies-into-jar

Comment: Does the app. have a GUI?  If so, a better deployment option might be [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS makes it simple to add extra Jars to the run-time class-path of an app.  Even better, JWS can provide a neat desktop shortcut or menu item (with custom icon) to launch the app.

Comment: @AndrewThompson could you use JWS when there is no GUI? And I guess you can also create a .jnlp and distribute it with your jars (no "Web" then)?

Comment: *"use JWS when there is no GUI?"* No. It is for apps. with a GUI.  As (I *thought* was) clearly explained in the link.  *"I guess you can also create a .jnlp and distribute it with your jars (no "Web" then)?"*  No, it is intended for launch from the internet or a network of some sort.  They don't call it 'Java **Web** Start'  and name the 'Java **Network** Launch Files' that extension for nothing.  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default Java class loader cannot find an embedded jar inside a jar file. You will need to set your Java program to use a class loader which can deal with embedded jar files. As fas as I know, I have not seen one in any opensource libraries so you may need to write one yourself.

Alternatively, you can extract all the jar files and combine the the content into a single jar file.

[Clean way to combine multiple jars? Preferably using Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515428/clean-way-to-combine-multiple-jars-preferably-using-ant)

Comment: The "no way to do it" is simply incorrect.  It just takes a Classloader which understands embedded jars - like one-jar.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Thanks for your corrections. I don't know why I said it like that either

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't have out-of-the-box support for embedding a jar within a jar. It can be achieved by writing a custom class loader, or using a tool that's already been written for this purpose: [Fat Jar](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/).