# how to make a swing as a exe file

Tags: java, class, exe

I have java class in which I am doing some business functionality, now what I want is a standalone file so that user dont need to write java command to execute it but he can directly  execute it as .exe file. Can anybody help me in this? I hope I was clear

Comment: It's a known question, already documented: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file

Comment: Also check this. Same question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330936/how-can-i-convert-a-jar-to-an-exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in simple word make a jar and in manifest file put the entry point that is you  swing main class which you want to run, Make sure you jar is correctly compiled with JRE version,

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to create a [JAR file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html) of your Java classes.

JAR file can be executed with: java -jar filename.jar

For default installation in Windows, there will be a file association between JAR files and Java, such that one can double click on the jar file to execute it (i.e., it behaves like an exe file).

Answer (score 2):

First make a jar file and then wrap your jar file into .exe. There are plenty softwares available.
Just google jar to exe

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/). It encapsulate a jar into a .exe.

It has a lot of other useful functionalities such as checking for the correct JRE version or giving download links in case Java is not installed.

Comment: but I have a java class which is using some other jar also say poi-3.9 jar. how to make it now executable now?

Comment: @Pulkit you can then use "jar-in-jar" embedding, as described in [that other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312909/java-create-jar-executable-with-dependant-jars-embedded)