# Create a jar with dependencies from bash

Tags: java, bash, jar, classpath

First of all I want to say that I do not want to use Maven, Ant, Gradle, any IDE or similar for this task.

I want to make a runnable jar using a bash script. The jar should includes all jar-content from my "libs" folder.

I have started this script and it "almost" works(until the jar creattion):

```
#!/bin/bash

#Setup
libs=$(find libs -name "*.jar" -print0 | xargs -0 | sed -e 's/ /:/g')
tmp2=$(sed -e 's/:/\n ..\//g' <<< $libs)
tmp2=../$tmp2
libs=$libs:src
mkdir tmp

#Compile
javac -d tmp -classpath "$libs" src/main/PublishData.java


#Create manifest
cd tmp
echo "Main-Class: main.PublishData" >> m.mf
echo "Class-Path: $tmp2" >> m.mf

#Build jar
jar cvfm thejar.jar m.mf *
```

An m.mf example file would look like this:

```
Main-Class: MyMain
Class-Path: ../libs/1.jar
 ../libs/2.jar
```

The file structure looks like this:

```
├── src
├── tmp (created by the script, jar cvfm thejar.jar m.mf * is run here)
├── libs
│   ├── jar1
│   ├── jar2
```

The jar file is created and can be executed but the referenced jars are not found.
(E.g: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/MongoClient`
)

It seams to me like the jar program could not find the jars.

**How can I successfully "include" my jars from the libs dir?**

---

UPDATE:

Every line in the "Class-Path:" section of a manifest file needs to start and end with a white space this caused the class-path to break.

Comment: Maybe this post can answer your question: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/8312977/2522681](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8312977/2522681)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach looks good in general.

Relative paths work in the manifest but you need to make sure that the paths are available at runtime. So if you say "load `../libs/foo.jar`", then for the classloading to work, you need to be in the `src/`, `tmp/` or `libs/` when you start the application.

The main problem is that Java silently ignores JARs which it can't find. I hesitate to call this a feature, especially since so many people run into problems starting a Java application. So you will have to painstakingly find out what works and what doesn't.

To make things more simple, I suggest that you JAR all the classes of your project as well and then create a pure "classpath" JAR (i.e. no classes, just a manifest file with the classpath + the main class). That way, all your dependencies work the same.

Another thing you should try is to write a small project (just the hello world kind) where you can test your "create manifest JAR" script.

That said, my approach is to create a main class which accepts a path as arguments (the absolute path to the libs folder). It then lists all the JAR files in the folder (plus some debug output so I can see what it finds) and creates a new `URLClassLoader` with those URLs. That way, I can debug classpath issues easily plus my "start" script work like this:

```
BASE=$(cd $( dirname "$0" ) > /dev/null ; pwd )

java -jar $BASE/starter.jar $BASE/libs
```