# In Maven project, a class is found in local jar file at compile time, but not run time. why?

Tags: maven

In a Maven project, I can include the classes with no problem.

However, during the runtime, I get `ClassNotFoundException` when I try to create an instance of that class.

> Part of the *pom.xml* file:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>acmeGamesGroupId</groupId>
            <artifactId>acmegames</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${acmegameslibs}\acme-1.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

Why can a class be found during compile-time, but not in the run-time? What do I need to do in the pom.xml file? help.

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935135/maven-and-adding-jars-to-system-scope ?

Answer (score 0):

You need more info.  What is your execution environment: native java, tomcat, what?  But my guess is your app is delivered as a jar file. 
 Unexpectedly the Java class loader [cannot find classes in embedded jar files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312909/java-create-jar-executable-with-dependant-jars-embedded)