# Where to deploy a jar dependency of my webservice?

Tags: java, jar, dependencies, apache-axis

My webservice depends upon a jar (which contains a custom Exception class among others).

When I deploy simply my webservice without this jar, axis2 complains that the Exception class is not known.

So I guess that I must deploy my jar too... But I feel reluctant to put it in: `tomcat\webapps\axis2\WEB-INF\lib`, since it's already filled with lots of axis2 and 3rd party jars...

i'd prefer something like `tomcat\webapps\axis2\WEB-INF\usr\lib`

Where would you put it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider deploying your webservice and it's dependencies as a single WAR web application. Then you could put your dependency in WEB-INF/lib of your webapp.

Comment: And how do I do that ? I have two projects, one jar and one war, how do I include the jar so as it becomes only one war ?

Comment: It depends on your build system. If you build your project with Maven - simply add your jar as dependency in your pom.xml. If you are using kind of IDE like Eclipse - refer to your IDE help how to establish dependency relationship between the projects. And as an ugly solution you can just put your compiled jar into deployed WAR WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse, and also Ant: it should work with Ant... Why is the lattest ugly (jar in WEB-INF/lib) ?

Comment: Jar in WEB-INF is not ugly itself. Ugly is placing it here with your hands instead of build system.

Comment: I used the technique explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/515428/clean-way-to-combine-multiple-jars-preferably-using-ant  with the Ant zipgroupfileset tag.

Answer (score 3):

If you're deploying an Axis2 AAR, you can put the jar into a `lib` directory inside the AAR.