# a Web Service deployed (as an aar) file to Axis2

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

I have a Web Service deployed (as an aar) file to Axis2, but the dependencies (in the form of .jar files within the lib directory of the aar file) are not found on execution. They do get used properly if I copy them into the WEB-INF lib directory of the Axis2 installation, but this is not an ideal workaround.
Does anybody know of any configuration settings I might have missed? Has anybody got a 
aar file (on OC4J or other server) with Axis2 v1.2? I'm not sure whether my problem is with Axis2, so might have to deploy the service to a Tomcat server to check but would rather not go through that cycle if someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks,

Comment: Axis2 1.2 is pretty old. [They are currently maintaining 1.6.x](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/download.cgi). You should start by upgrading to something more current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the jars into a lib directory inside the AAR. as pointed out in  [Where to deploy a jar dependency of my webservice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533735/where-to-deploy-a-jar-dependency-of-my-webservice)

This will help you understand the structure of the aar file -http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/quickstartguide.html