# Creating JAR file from Class file & Jar file

Tags: java

I have a jar file and a class file. I want to create a single JAR file from both. Is it possible? Please help me on the same. 
I have tried 
Jar -cf new.jar sample1.class sample2.jar

It didnot help

Comment: Just use a zip file editor to add the class file to the jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but technically you can do it with:

```
cp sample2.jar new.jar
jar uvf new.jar sample1.class
```

Of course, if you already had class sample1.class inside sample2.jar, it will be overwritten ( "u" == update ) by sample1.class

Answer (score 1):

Transfer all your classes into a folder, say it is in `C:\Folder\Project\`

Go to the same folder from command prompt. And execute the following code :

```
jar cfv Project.jar *
```

In the above command, `c will create jar`, `f will transfer the content into the file i.e Project.jar` and `v will print the process done into the console`.

`* (WildCard)` will take all the files present in the folder and the corresponding jar would be created in the same folder.

You can find more information the DOCS. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html

In the meanwhile i would suggest you to go through the below link, where you can do the same with a build tool like `Ant or Maven.`

[Clean way to combine multiple jars? Preferably using Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515428/clean-way-to-combine-multiple-jars-preferably-using-ant)